# pass Ctrl+] over socket connection using java

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I have connected telnet server using socket, I am passing various command using this connection, now as per my requirement after getting output I have to pass command like "Ctrl+]" over socket using java.

can you anyone explain me how I pass the same command using java.

below are the method for reference:

```
 public void logout(){
                System.out.println("TelnetHelper : Inside logout()");
                try {
                        telnetWrapper.send("\u001d");
                        telnetWrapper.send("quit");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("logout() : IOExcepton - "+e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("logout() : General Excepton - "+e.getMessage());
                }
                System.out.println("TelnetHelper : logout() Finished");
        }
```

But this is not working in my case

Answer (score 1):

Just close the connection, I suppose that would be telnetWrapper.close();

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to send `\u001b` ...

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

Comment: I'm not sure where you found the `CTRL+]` code on that page, but it seems to be a keyboard shortcut for MS's telnet app, not a VT100 code. In that case, jacool's suggestion to just close the connection seems appropriate.

Comment: They're standard codes .. look here http://www.asciitable.com anyway if all you're trying to do is close the connection then yeah that's all you need to do. I thought you were trying to do something clever ...

Comment: ASCII `0x1b` is simply `ESC`. I don't see how it answers the user's question.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but a [search for `CTRL+[`](https://www.google.com/search?q=telnet+ctrl%2B[&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) turns up only MS's `CTRL+]` shortcut to leave the session.